# Configure macOS Notification Center Banner self-dismiss time

Tags: macos, notifications

How can I reduce the amount of time before a macOS / OS X Notification Center banner dismisses itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your terminal and run this command

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime SECONDS
```

where SECONDS is a number for how many seconds you want the banner to be displayed.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work again in Monterey, the defaults command takes no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you cannot change the duration. But you can [dismiss it manually](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht5362) by placing the cursor over the banner and doing a two finger swipe from left to right on a trackpad (or a one finger swipe on a magic mouse).